# В tars не могу создать спрайт

Tags: css, stylus, tars

Файл лежит тут:

[image: файл png]

в коде я вызываю миксин так: `bg("pdf")`,

но в итоге для браузера прописан следующий путь:

`url("../img/png-sprite/96dpi/null")`

почему так?